# How to get scrape DIV having Class or ID containing specific text

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML scraped from a site

```
<div>
 <div id="content1">
 </div>
 <div id="content3">
 </div>
 <div id="content22">
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I iterate over all the DIVs having ID starting with `content`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to use a [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select('div[id^=content]')
```

The `^=` syntax specifies that the `id` attribute value should *start* with `content`.

You can get the same result using a [regular expression filter](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-regular-expression) passed in as the `id` argument to [`element.find_all()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
import re

soup.find_all('div', id=re.compile('^content'))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> sample = '''\
... <div>
...  <div id="content1">
...  </div>
...  <div id="content3">
...  </div>
...  <div id="content22">
...  </div>
... </div>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(sample)
>>> soup.select('div[id^=content]')
[<div id="content1">
</div>, <div id="content3">
</div>, <div id="content22">
</div>]
>>> soup.find_all('div', id=re.compile('^content'))
[<div id="content1">
</div>, <div id="content3">
</div>, <div id="content22">
</div>]
```